# python. Машинное обучение. Прогнозирование

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, xgboost

Доброго времени суток. Занимался задачами регрессии с использование sclearn и xgboost. Однако задача прогнозирования слегка отличается, можете ли вы привести пример в каком виде должны быть данные и пример кода на python для работы c использование xgboost.
В задачах регрессии я подобным образом собирал данные в виде подобного набора строк

```
1;34;234;234;123;2;321;2;123213;24534;3;278
```

Где входной вектор был n-1 параметров, а предсказываемое значение - последний столбец. Насколько я понимаю в задачах прогнозирования, сама строка это один и тот же параметр который изменяется во времени, в то время как в задачах регрессии несколько различных параметров по которым предсказываем один. Вопрос - чем отличаются задачи планирования и регрессии на уровне программирования? 
Т.е.
входные данные имеют вид

```
    x0        x1        x2        x3        x4        x5        y
  0.392689  0.117810  0.242750  0.931792  0.972802  0.898693  0.429941
  0.569055  0.622889  0.762683  0.095271  0.101407  0.510155  0.542256
  0.939509  0.993534  0.772005  0.164555  0.800897  0.591883  0.190720
  0.284297  0.292773  0.290652  0.045383  0.564894  0.347683  0.014610
```

где мы предсказываем значение y. И данные имею такой вид:

```
x1 0.284297  0.292773  0.290652  0.045383  0.564894  0.347683  0.014610  0.961696
x2 0.939509  0.993534  0.772005  0.164555  0.800897  0.591883  0.190720  0.040162
```

где надо предсказать дальнейшие значения x1, x2, .. в чем отличие в плане кода?

```
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris, load_digits, load_boston
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error,mean_squared_error,median_absolute_error, accuracy_score
df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv',";",header=None)
X_train = df.drop(7,axis=1)
Y_train = df[7]
test_data = pd.read_csv('file2.csv',";",header=None)
X_test = test_data.drop(7,axis=1)
Y_test = test_data[7]
xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(max_depth)
cl = xgb_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
predictions = cl.predict(X_test)
actuals = Y_test
print(mean_absolute_error(actuals, predictions))
print(mean_squared_error(actuals, predictions))
print(median_absolute_error(actuals, predictions))
```

Условно данный код, одинаково будет предсказывать и дальнейшее значение x1 для второй выборки и y - для первой?

Comment: вы хотите предсказывать сразу несколько выходных параметров?

Comment: Да, у нас получается для задач регрессии достаточно определить последний параметр.
А для задач прогнозирования, если строка из n параметров последние n/3 параметров.

Comment: Мб понятнее станет. Если у нас данные имеют вид:
x0        x1        x2        x3        x4        x5        x6         y
0.284297  0.292773  0.290652  0.045383  0.564894  0.347683  0.014610  0.961696
и мы предсказываем y. 
И если данные имею такой вид 
x1 0.284297  0.292773  0.290652  0.045383  0.564894  0.347683  0.014610  0.961696 и надо предсказать дальнейшие значения x0 в чем различие в плане кода?

Comment: я не понял как у вас столбцы (x1, x2) стали строками - или вы их так просто для удобства представили? PS ваш код будет предсказывать `y` для набора параметров `X`. `x` он предсказывать не будет

Comment: Мы транспонировали первый файл и теперь каждая строка это отдельный параметр, который нам нужно предсказать.

Comment: Что у вас входные данные и что вы предсказываете __после__ транспонирования?

Comment: Нам нужно предсказать последний столбец каждого параметра. По предыдущем значениям этого параметра

Comment: т.е. у вас будут добавляться столбцы (новые параметры)? И связаны ли параметры между собой или они независимы?

Comment: Да, будут добавляться новые столбцы, это будет тот же параметр, но имеющий спустя время другое значение. Про параметры мутно, если честно, по идее будет тупо постоянно растущая одна строка. Банальный пример - строка это изменение курса доллара в течении времени и нам нужно предсказать, каким оно будет в дальнейшем.

Comment: Тогда это линейная регрессия, где в классическом виде данные представлены в виде матрицы размерностью `(m x 2)` с двумя __столбцами__ - время и курс. Все известные мне алгоритмы ожидают параметры (например `время`) в виде набора столбцов, а не строк.

Answer (score 8):

**Ответ на вопрос до правки**

> как разбивать на обучающую и проверочную выборку?

Для таких задач идеально подходят модули Pandas и Numpy, которые позволяют работать без циклов (векторизированные решения) с целыми матрицами и векторами, что на порядки быстрее по сравнению с обработкой в циклах.

Вот небольшой пример:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate random DataFrame (shape: 10, 8)
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,8)).add_prefix('x')

In [14]: df.columns = df.columns[:-1].tolist() + ['y']

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
         x0        x1        x2        x3        x4        x5        x6         y
0  0.392689  0.117810  0.242750  0.931792  0.972802  0.898693  0.429941  0.619093
1  0.569055  0.622889  0.762683  0.095271  0.101407  0.510155  0.542256  0.848998
2  0.939509  0.993534  0.772005  0.164555  0.800897  0.591883  0.190720  0.040162
3  0.284297  0.292773  0.290652  0.045383  0.564894  0.347683  0.014610  0.961696
4  0.065868  0.974128  0.749756  0.778895  0.872915  0.585320  0.851837  0.408333
5  0.818768  0.343451  0.985583  0.860080  0.876103  0.554149  0.132387  0.506820
6  0.713177  0.567278  0.587488  0.459199  0.082245  0.677964  0.229960  0.265138
7  0.751670  0.902665  0.353395  0.975563  0.823437  0.742916  0.760047  0.567249
8  0.106809  0.068440  0.075260  0.435980  0.412090  0.226181  0.909518  0.714608
9  0.281475  0.641496  0.695424  0.993351  0.958840  0.457999  0.203841  0.007968
```

теперь мы можем нарезать данные так как нам удобно

Например если нам нужны все столбцы кроме последнего:

```
In [16]: df.iloc[:, :-1]
Out[16]:
         x0        x1        x2        x3        x4        x5        x6
0  0.392689  0.117810  0.242750  0.931792  0.972802  0.898693  0.429941
1  0.569055  0.622889  0.762683  0.095271  0.101407  0.510155  0.542256
2  0.939509  0.993534  0.772005  0.164555  0.800897  0.591883  0.190720
3  0.284297  0.292773  0.290652  0.045383  0.564894  0.347683  0.014610
4  0.065868  0.974128  0.749756  0.778895  0.872915  0.585320  0.851837
5  0.818768  0.343451  0.985583  0.860080  0.876103  0.554149  0.132387
6  0.713177  0.567278  0.587488  0.459199  0.082245  0.677964  0.229960
7  0.751670  0.902665  0.353395  0.975563  0.823437  0.742916  0.760047
8  0.106809  0.068440  0.075260  0.435980  0.412090  0.226181  0.909518
9  0.281475  0.641496  0.695424  0.993351  0.958840  0.457999  0.203841
```

или все столбцы начинающиеся с `x`:

```
In [17]: df.filter(regex='^x\d+')
Out[17]:
         x0        x1        x2        x3        x4        x5        x6
0  0.392689  0.117810  0.242750  0.931792  0.972802  0.898693  0.429941
1  0.569055  0.622889  0.762683  0.095271  0.101407  0.510155  0.542256
2  0.939509  0.993534  0.772005  0.164555  0.800897  0.591883  0.190720
3  0.284297  0.292773  0.290652  0.045383  0.564894  0.347683  0.014610
4  0.065868  0.974128  0.749756  0.778895  0.872915  0.585320  0.851837
5  0.818768  0.343451  0.985583  0.860080  0.876103  0.554149  0.132387
6  0.713177  0.567278  0.587488  0.459199  0.082245  0.677964  0.229960
7  0.751670  0.902665  0.353395  0.975563  0.823437  0.742916  0.760047
8  0.106809  0.068440  0.075260  0.435980  0.412090  0.226181  0.909518
9  0.281475  0.641496  0.695424  0.993351  0.958840  0.457999  0.203841
```

разделяем набор данных на обучающую и проверочную выборки, предварительно перетасовав данные случайным образом:

```
In [19]: df_train, df_test = np.split(df.sample(frac=1), [6])

In [20]: df_train
Out[20]:
         x0        x1        x2        x3        x4        x5        x6         y
3  0.284297  0.292773  0.290652  0.045383  0.564894  0.347683  0.014610  0.961696
2  0.939509  0.993534  0.772005  0.164555  0.800897  0.591883  0.190720  0.040162
9  0.281475  0.641496  0.695424  0.993351  0.958840  0.457999  0.203841  0.007968
1  0.569055  0.622889  0.762683  0.095271  0.101407  0.510155  0.542256  0.848998
8  0.106809  0.068440  0.075260  0.435980  0.412090  0.226181  0.909518  0.714608
7  0.751670  0.902665  0.353395  0.975563  0.823437  0.742916  0.760047  0.567249

In [21]: df_test
Out[21]:
         x0        x1        x2        x3        x4        x5        x6         y
4  0.065868  0.974128  0.749756  0.778895  0.872915  0.585320  0.851837  0.408333
0  0.392689  0.117810  0.242750  0.931792  0.972802  0.898693  0.429941  0.619093
6  0.713177  0.567278  0.587488  0.459199  0.082245  0.677964  0.229960  0.265138
5  0.818768  0.343451  0.985583  0.860080  0.876103  0.554149  0.132387  0.506820
```

PS практически все известные мне библиотеки по машинному обучению принимают в качестве входных данных Pandas.DataFrame's, Pandas.Series, Numpy.Arra's.

Т.е. что-то вроде:

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(...)
clf.fit(df_train.filter(regex='^x'), df_train.loc[:, 'y'])
```

Comment: Вопрос состоял не в том как работать с матрицами в питоне и какими модулями это сделать, С таким же успехом я могу и другими модулями все обрабатывать. Вопрос в том насколько сильно задача прогнозирования отличается от задач регрессии в которых для предсказания используется несколько параметров, в то время как в прогнозировании 1, но изменяющийся.

Comment: @KordDEM, регрессии тоже относятся к прогнозированию - прогноз недискретных величин (значений). Что вы имеете в виду под `в то время как в прогнозировании 1, но изменяющийся`?

Comment: Уточнил. Вкратце, даже в представленном вами примере вы предсказываете только последний столбец, различие лишь в том, что тут строка это изменение одного параметра в течении времени, а если брать задачу регрессии, то каждый столбец отдельный параметр. Надеюсь грамотно сформулировал)
И.З. зачем перемешивать строки, когда это абсолютно не зависимые записи?

Comment: строка (кроме последнего элемента) - это набор параметров, с помощью которых мы хотим предсказывать последнее значение (target). Это справедливо и для задач регрессии и для задач классификации

Comment: Т.е. отличие зависит только от собираемых данных?
А задачи классификации и регрессии по данной вами формулировки не отличаются? Просто интересно докопаться до сути.

Comment: Для того чтобы дать вам показательный и понятный ответ - приведите небольшой пример входных и выходных данных - тогда можно будет показать на примере...

Comment: Вряд ли наглядным примером, что-то объясниться=)
Как пример есть выборка из 1-10 (различные) параметров 11 параметр предсказываем:
1;34;234;234;123;2;321;2;123213;24534;3;278 
278 - предсказываем, параметры разноплановые.
Однако есть та же самая строка и так же предсказываем 278, но вся строка это изменение одного и того же параметра, так в чем различие для программиста?